# Ranking values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this running in a while loop to add to the array every time it goes through it. However, my issue is I am trying to assign ranks for each value. Saw `horse1` had `AP=51` , `EP=47`, `SP= 32`, `FX=20`. `Horse2` had `AP=52`, `EP = 55`, `SP=30` and `F=19`. I am trying to make it print on the screen like so:

```
          AP   EP   SP   FX  
Horse 1   2    2    1    1

Horse 2   1    1    2    2
```

And etc for however many horses there are.

Here is the code I have. I am not very well versed in PHP but I thought this was the way to go.

```
$allstats[]= array
(
"AP"=>"x".$AP,
"EP"=>"x".$EP,
"SP"=>"x".$SP,
"FX"=>"x".$FX,
"Horse"=>$horse,
);

$APranks[$AP];
$EPranks[$EP];
$SPranks[$SP];
$FXranks[$FX];

ksort($APranks,2);
ksort($EPranks,2);
ksort($SPranks,2);
ksort($FXranks,2);
$FinalAP=(array_keys($APRanks,$AP));
?>
<div id="Rankings">
<? echo array_search($AP,$FinalAP);?><? echo array_search($EP,$EPranks);?><? echo         array_search($SP,$SPranks);?><? echo array_search($FX,$FXranks);?>
</div>
```

Comment: "Here is the code I have" There is no code. Show your code and the results you get with that code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't indent it for some reason

Comment: @ChadNathanJones, there is no reason to not to indent your code properly. You indent not just to share it with others but for your sake too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your horse array is like this,

```
$horses[1]=array('AP'=>51,'EP'=>47,'SP'=>32,'FX'=>20);
$horses[2]=array('AP'=>52,'EP'=>55,'SP'=>30,'FX'=>19);

$horse_values = array('AP','EP','SP','FX');
$horse_rank = array();

foreach($horse_values as $k=>$val)
{
    uasort($horses, create_function('$a, $b', 'return custom_sort($a, $b, "'.$val.'");'));

    $i=1;
    foreach($horses as $l=>$horse)
    {
        $horse_rank[$l][$val] = $i;
        $i++;
    }
}

function custom_sort( $a, $b, $meta )  {
    if ( $a[$meta] == $b[$meta] )
        return 0;
    else if ( $a[$meta] > $b[$meta] )
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
    //echo "$a, $b, $meta<hr>"; // Debugging output
}

arsort($horse_rank); //sorting the final rank array based on horse number
print_r($horse_rank);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [AP] => 2
            [EP] => 2
            [SP] => 1
            [FX] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [AP] => 1
            [EP] => 1
            [SP] => 2
            [FX] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: That was perfect. Had to change a couple of things to add the Horse name but that was it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!! Please accept the answer and post solution in your original post :)